# Irregular self complementary graph.

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a family of irregular self complementary graph?

Or are all self complementary graphs regular?

Comment: The $4$-path is self-complementary, and it isn't regular.

Comment: Your first question is harder than I guessed at first; I refer you to this thesis: [Alastair Farrugia](http://www.alastairfarrugia.net/sc-graph/sc-graph-survey.pdf).